# Looking for way to replace many "when...thenReturn" statements in test method

Tags: junit, mockito

I'm writing a [JUnit](http://junit.org/) test on a method that is interacting primarily with classes in [org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/package-summary.html) (like [HSSFWorkbook](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html), [HSSFFont](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFFont.html) and [HSSFCellStyle](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCellStyle.html)).

The method ultimately builds up and returns an `HSSFWorkbook` object.

In order to build up the `HSSFWorkbook` object, methods like `workbook.createFont()` and `workbook.createCellStyle()` are invoked.

I currently mock out the objects like this in the `setup` class of my unit test

```
workbook = mock(HSSFWorkbook.class);
font = mock(HSSFFont.class);
cellStyle = mock(HSSFCellStyle.class);
```

Then, in my test method, I invoke the following to avoid NPEs

```
when(workbook.createFont()).thenReturn(font);
when(workbook.createCellStyle()).thenReturn(cellStyle);
```

I'm discovering I'll have to do many more of those in order to avoid the NPEs and I'm wondering if there's a way that I can avoid writing all of those "when...thenReturn" statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one of the rules of Mocking is: Never mock types you don't own. Another rule is a stubbed call on a mock, shouldn't return another mock.

The reason is in front of you :).

If your class **only** deals with creating the `HSSFWorkbook`, then treat the tests as integration tests and use the real library. If your class does something else too, then move all the *other* stuff to other classes (this is to follow the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle))

Comment: Agreed 100 % percent. If POI changes his way of doing things in any revision your actual tests won't catch the changes and you will be in trouble figuring what's actually wrong. _"Another rule is a stubbed call on a mock, shouldn't return another mock."_ in other words it means you are breaking the Demeter Law, and in proper design you'd want to avoid that, practicing the _"tell, don't ask"_ principle (same as following the Demeter Law) with an intermediate layer might help you to hide the underlying of POI, and it will be your types.

Comment: There's also another thing that might save you a few lines with Mockito, using the [`RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) answer will help you for legacy stuff. But still, it is not recommended anyway for goo designs.

Comment: Nice answer - thanks.  Unfortunately, I can't refactor the existing code (which is BADLY in need of refactoring) at this time.  Right now I've been tasked to just write unit tests for the existing code.

Comment: So, I guess then for now I should test the functionality of this method as it pertains to code that we own and then use a real HSSFWorkbook on the other code in the method - does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct to test it with the real HSSFWorkbook. Otherwise the test will be quite complex (because of the mocking) and will have little value.